# Django: URL Path not found jumps into next app

Tags: django, django-urls

I have two apps:

backend
shop

I my urls in main app dir:

```
path('backend/', include('backend.urls')),
path('', include('shop.urls')),
```

the problem is if I write in my url: localhost:8000/backend/abc which not exist Django jumps over to shop.urls and the app is crashing because it can not find the slug and the query goes in fail.

How can I prevent if I go to the url /backend/somethingwhichnotexist is returning an 404 and not search in other app urls for this folder? I have thought that this is one of the main reason for split the urls in app folders.

Here are some urls from backend/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views as backend_views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from froala_editor import views
from django.conf.urls import include
urlpatterns = [
path('stamdata/', backend_views.edit_masterdata),
path('praefikser/', backend_views.edit_prefixes),
path('leverandorer/', backend_views.suppliers_view),
path('leverandorer/add', backend_views.add_supplier),

]

handler404 = 'backend.views.page_not_found_view'
```

shop/urls.py

here the url stops:

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug_subcategory>/', butik_views.cat_or_article),
```

normally I don't want that a backend urls switches to frontend view

regards
Christopher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I fixed it with

shop/views.py

```
if category_slug == 'backend':
    response = render(
        request,
        'backend/404.html',
    )
    response.status_code = 404
    return response
else:
```

until I found another solution. It looks like that the URL dispatcher is working like this:

> Django runs through each URL pattern, in order, and stops at the first
> one that matches the requested URL, matching against path_info.

So for now I did not found another way.

Edit:

I added this in the end of backend/urls.py:

```
re_path(r'^.*/$', backend_views.page_not_found_view)
```

so after all working urls it goes to all other to the 404 view.

Answer (score 0):

You you said Django run through all of the URL patterns and stops till it finds its matching URL. SO, what has happen here is that when you type a URL with localhost:8000/backend/abc/ it runs through all the URLS before returning 404 to the client. So, it stops at the URL that support any string with 2 parameters in your case below URL.

```
path('<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug_subcategory>/', butik_views.cat_or_article),
```

To get a 404 by adding a static word in you URL.

```
path('shop/<slug:category_slug>/<slug:slug_subcategory>/', butik_views.cat_or_article),
```

or

```
path('backend/', include('backend.urls')),
path('shop/', include('shop.urls')),
```

Comment: Yes that is what I also evaluated, but which shopsystem do you know which uses /shop as prefix? Non professional, or if you have two products installed and have two physically folders for each app. There must be a way but I came not to this. I can also separate backend and frontend with two urls (.com and .app) or subdomains (backend.... and www....) but this should be the least way.